# Rsyslog only log snort and dns

Tags: linux, dns, syslog

I'm currently running Graylog to receive logs from my Pi-Hole and Snort instance.
However, rsyslog is sending all logs e.g. java, sudo etc as well.

How do I configure Rsyslog to only log Snort specific and Pi-Hole entries. Nothing else needs to be logged.

My current /etc/rsyslog.conf file looks as below:

```
module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10") #used for Pi-Hole logging
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog


#SNORT Data
*.* @127.0.0.1:5140;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format

#PiHole Data
input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/pihole.log"
      StateFile="/var/run/pihole.log.state"
      Tag="pihole"
      Severity="info"
      Facility="local7")
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the # character to the beginning of the line to comment it out.
For example: #module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging